# Django - How to append to a Django queryset (values)

Tags: python, django

how do I append a dictionary into a Django queryset? I did .values on the queryset already, but it still classifies as a queryset and when I try to use .append on it, this error came up

```
AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'append'
```

Here is my code: (start and end are variables passed in to denote the start month and end month of the selected range)

```
qs = CustomerInformation.objects.filter(salesDepartment__in=[d]).filter(created_date__range=(start,end))
qs = qs.annotate(date=TruncMonth('created_date')).values('date').annotate(lead_count=Count('status',filter=Q(status="lead"))).annotate(client_count=Count('status',filter=Q(status="client")))
qs = qs.values('date', 'client_count', 'lead_count')
```

All I want to do is to add the missing dates to the queryset, like for example if my queryset has date: April 2020 and June 2020, but is missing May 2020 due to CustomerInformation not having any instances with created_date in range of May 2020, hence I want to be able to insert a dictionary with date: May 2020 and lead_count and client_count 0 so that my data visualisation would work properly

Thanks all, all help is appreciated!

Comment: convert it to list: `list(qs)`. But I don't suggest you to do it, because items' type of query set is not dict, so you must have a type checking later.

Comment: I remember I saw your question before, so you could consider that: construct a new type similar to list which is iterable, then fill the query results into it, then use this new type instead of queryset directly.

Comment: @YangHG what do you mean by items' type of query set?

Comment: what I am doing now is to convert it to a list using list comprehension, would that work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not append to a qs, unless you're adding data to the database. 
If you want to you can convert to a list, then add items.

You could create a generator that outputs additional values where needed too.

Something like:

```
def getDatat():
    qs = CustomerInformation.objects.filter(salesDepartment__in=[d]).filter(created_date__range=(start,end))
    qs = qs.annotate(date=TruncMonth('created_date')).values('date').annotate(lead_count=Count('status',filter=Q(status="lead"))).annotate(client_count=Count('status',filter=Q(status="client")))
    qs = qs.values('date', 'client_count', 'lead_count')
    this_v = None
    for next_v in qs:
         if this_v is None:
            this_v = next_v
            yield this_v
            continue
         # Do logic for checking if there's any needed extra values between this_v and next_V
         # yield extra values
         this_v = next_v
         yield this_v
```